# KStream cloud spring produce message

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I have this kstream consumer + produser

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processMessage() {
        return input -> input.map(
                (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key, process(value)));
}
```

But how can I use only producer with kafka stream?